# How to fix BottomNavigationBar disappearance issue in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, dart

I am facing an issue with my bottom navigation bar. The problem is that the bottom navigation bar disappears whenever I navigate to another page.

I am using the following code to navigate to another page:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (BuildContext context) => WorkoutsPage()
));
```

Here is a summarized part of the BottomBar

```
class BottomBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BottomBar> createState() => _BottomBarState();
}

class _BottomBarState extends State<BottomBar> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    HomeScreen(),
    WorkoutsPage(),
    ................
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
      //print('Tapped index is: ${_selectedIndex}');
    });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions[_selectedIndex],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Column(
        children: [
          BottomNavigationBar(
            currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
            onTap: _onItemTapped,
            ..................................
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            items: const [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(FluentSystemIcons.ic_fluent_home_regular),
                  activeIcon: Icon(FluentSystemIcons.ic_fluent_home_filled),
                  label: "Home"),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon:
                      Icon(FluentSystemIcons.ic_fluent_clipboard_text_regular),
                  activeIcon:
                      Icon(FluentSystemIcons.ic_fluent_clipboard_text_filled),
                  label: "Plan"),
```

Here is the main.dart

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => _defaultHome,
        '/home': (context) => const BottomBar(),
        '/login': (context) => const LoginPage(),
        '/register': (context) => const RegisterPage(),
      },
    );
  }
```

My question what should I do to keep the bottombar when I use

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (BuildContext context) => WorkoutsPage()
));
```

after clicking a submit button or something

Comment: A pushed new route means another page, presumably another `Scaffold`, which will have its own `bottomNavigationBar`. You need to add a navigation bar to each `Scaffold` where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

**BottomBar** is a page. When you use *pushReplacement*, You move to another *Scaffold* page that is no BottomBar.
An alternative is to turn Column widget of *bottomNavigationBar* into a separate **StatefulWidget** and start passing it in all *Scaffold* pages.
Keep *selectedIndex* as a global variable so that its value remains even when you change to another route.